# Первоапрельское оформление enSO - как будто его взломали!!! 

Tags: обсуждение, 1-апреля

С английским сайтом что-то случилось

Comment: Интересный способ обратить внимание на первоапрельское оформление enSO. Подача материала - facepalm.

Answer (score 4):

У нас тоже хочу!

Вариант со звёздами классный! А ещё марио и фейсбучный. Кстати, марио шире остальных.

Comment: о, а я и не заметил, что там переключать можно